# Qt widget disobeys drop in Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt 4.6 based app that is compiled on both a Linux machine and Windows machine. I have two widgets:
 1. allowdrop=false and drop type is internal only
 2. allowdrop=false and drop type is no drag and drop

On the linux machine, dragging the first control's items to seconds does nothing and even shows the "no" symbol for not allowed to drop. On the Windows machine, everything except the second widget disallows drops. On Windows, when dragging the firsts' object to second, it allows the drag/drop and then crashes the program due to that move supposed to be blocked.

I'm guessing this is a QT bug, but is there something I can do short of filing a bug report that will make it behave on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

check mimetypes in dragEnterEvent, maybe Linux and Windows generate different mimetypes for your elements

Comment: I'm not sure about how checking the mimetype would help if it was already told to not accept "anything", but I made a dragenterevent for the object that shouldn't be accepting the object. calling setAccepted(false) does not stop it either.